# How to implement simple tkinter GUI app with a single input box?

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is my code and I essentially want there to be a line for input with the variable named `CITY`, and I am having issues doing it. I have tried using Tkinter input but was unable to do it and it just gave me errors.

```
from tkinter import *
import requests, json
import random
window = Tk()

window.title("Weather")

window.geometry('350x200')

def start():
    CITY = "London"
    BASE_URL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"
    API_KEY = "xxxxxxx"
    URL = BASE_URL + "q=" + CITY + "&appid=" + API_KEY
    response = requests.get(URL)
    if response.status_code == 200:
       data = response.json()
       main = data['main']
       temperature = main['temp']
       humidity = main['humidity']
       pressure = main['pressure']
       report = data['weather']
       temperature = round(int(temperature) - 273.15)
       Label(window, foreground='blue',text=f"{CITY:-^30}").grid(column=0, row=1)
       Label(window, text=f"Temperature: {temperature}"+"C").grid(column=0, row=2)
       Label(window, text=f"Humidity: {humidity}"+"%").grid(column=0, row=3)
       Label(window, text=f"Pressure: {pressure}").grid(column=0, row=4)
       Label(window, text=f"Weather Report: {report[0]['description']}").grid(column=0, row=5)
    else:
       # showing the error message
       print("Error in the HTTP request")

start()


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What error is that

Comment: The code in your question results in an `response.status_code` value of `401`. Please provide a runnable [mre] illustrating what you want to do.

Comment: @martineau The code works fine if you provide a valid API key.  But I don't think OP will share the key.

Comment: @acw1668: Then needing one would not be in a [mre] — I doubt it has anything to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by adding an Entry widget to your window and then accessing its content. To add an Entry widget, you can use the following (after `window` has been set):

```
ent_city = tk.Entry(window, width=20)
ent_city.pack()
```

The content of the `ent_city` field can then be accessed through `ent_city.get()`. In `start()`, this could look like this:

```
def start():
    CITY = ent_city.get()
```